# Connection.query function is being skipped and not executed within if statement

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have setup a couple of express endpoints to build a attendance registry system using node and angular, everything works fine, except,in the '/punchin' endpoint, where i used a couple of connection.query function within a if statement is being skipped and not executed

I have tried using promises, con.query(sqlQuery).then().catch(), its not working

```
app.post('/punchin',(req,res)=>{

const checkIfIdExists='SELECT uid FROM registerTbl WHERE uid="'+req.body.inData+'"'
    con.query(checkIfIdExists,(err,result)=>{
        if(result[0]===undefined)
        {
            return console.log('The entered unique id does not exist in our database')
        }
    })
        const checkIfStatIsUndefined='SELECT attendanceStatus FROM userAttendanceLog WHERE uid="'+req.body.inData+'" '
        con.query(checkIfStatIsUndefined,(err,result)=>{
            console.log(result)
            console.log(checkIfStatIsUndefined)
            if(!result[0])
            {
                console.log('line 68')
                const selectLogDetailForNewUser='SELECT name,uid FROM registerTbl WHERE uid="'+req.body.inData+'"'
                console.log('line 70' +selectLogDetailForNewUser)
                con.query(selectLogDetailForNewUser,(err,result)=>{
                    console.log('line 80' + sel)
                    console.log(result+'line 81')
                    const updateStatusForNewUser='INSERT INTO userAttendanceLog (name,uid,attendanceStatus) VALUES ("'+result[0].name+'","'+req.body.inData+'","1")'
                    con.query(updateStatusForNewUser,(err,result)=>{
                        if(err)
                        {
                            return console.log("Error in Posting")
                        }
                        res.send('Status updated')
                    })     
                })


            }


        })
```

expected result should be that the 2 connection.query function within the if statement should be executed, but it is not.

Comment: Which query is executing and which is not??

Answer (score 0):

You are conditioned to say that if the value of this query was an empty array and there was no object in zero index, execute condition. But when the result has a value, the true result is false with `!` not run it. So the result must be a value that does not fit the condition.

> if result.length == 0

```
console.log(result[0]) // undefined
```

and not undefined in javaScript is true

```
console.log(!result[0]) // true
```

So the condition does not apply but if result has information:

```
console.log(result[0]) // query result data
```

have data and array of object in result main is true in condition and not is that is false and if statement should not be executed

```
console.log(!result[0]) // false
```

if you run it delete `!` mark or change your condition for execute.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'yourPass',
    database: 'test'
});
function f() {
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");


        const checkIfIdExists = 'select 1 + 1'
        con.query(checkIfIdExists, (err, result) => {
            console.log(1, result)
            if (true) {
                return console.log('The entered unique id does not exist in our database')
            }
        })
        const checkIfStatIsUndefined = 'select 10 + 10 '
        con.query(checkIfStatIsUndefined, (err, result) => {
            console.log(10, result, result[0], !result[0])
            if (result[0]) {
                const selectLogDetailForNewUser = 'select 100 + 100'
                con.query(selectLogDetailForNewUser, (err, result) => {
                    console.log(100, result, err)
                    console.log("baba" + sel);
                    const updateStatusForNewUser = 'select 1000 + 1000'
                    con.query(updateStatusForNewUser, (err, result) => {
                        console.log(1000, result)
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log("Error in Posting")
                        }
                        //res.send('Status updated')
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    });
}

console.log(f());
```

Comment: Hello sir @mohammad Javad shmadi, I have tried already what you have told, sir. I used if(result[0]===undefined), and the if statement works, but the con.query function is not executing

Comment: which con.query? there is lot of con.query in your code? yo say expected result should be that the 2 connection.query function within the if statement should be executed.

Comment: Right after the console.log('line 68') sir, what I mean to say is, the console.log line is executing but not the 2 con.query function after the line console.log('line 68')

Comment: get console.log(err) inside of both callback, what print them? Put all your code inside   to `try{} catch(e){}` and log e in catch scope?

Comment: I tried it, it's not working sir, it seems, even inside the try block, the function is not executing, catch also not displaying any error,

Comment: `console.log('line 80' + sel); console.log(result+'line 81')` make error in your code. comment it. and add console log in above of res. send. and see log it?

Comment: I've simulated your code and it's working and printing all the logs. I'll put it above you check. My hope can help